# Interpreter problem (apparently) with a project in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I recently upgraded PyCharm (community version).  If it matters, I am running on a Mac OSX machine.  After the upgrade, I have one project in which PyCharm cannot find any python modules.  It can't find numpy, matplotlib, anything ...  I have checked a couple of other projects and they seem to be fine.  I noticed that somehow the interpreter for the project in question was not the same as for the others.  So I changed it to match the others.  But PyCharm still can't find the modules.  Any ideas what else I can do?

More generally, something like this happens every time I upgrade to a new PyCharm version.  The fix each time is a little different.  Any ideas on how I can prevent this in the first place?

EDIT: FWIW, I just now tried to create a new dummy project.  It has the same problem.  I notice that my two problem projects are created with a "venv" sub-directory.  My "good" projects don't have this thing.  Is this a clue to what is going on?

EDIT 2: OK, just realized that when creating a new project, I can select "New environment" or "Existing interpreter", and I want "Existing interpreter".  However, I would still like to know how one project that was working fine before is now hosed, and how I can fix it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, when you are creating a new project, you also opt to create a new virtual environment, which then is created (default) in that venv sub-directory.
But that would only apply to new projects, what is going on with your old projects, changing their project interpreter environment i do not understand.
So what i would say is you have some corrupt settings (e.g. in ~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2018.2 ), which are copied upon PyCharm upgrade.
You might try newly configure PyCharm by moving away those PyCharm preferences, so you can put them back later.

The Project configuration mainly, special the Project interpreter on the other hand is stored inside $PROJECT_ROOT/.idea and thus should not change.

Answer (score 1):

Your project is most likely pointing to the wrong interpreter. E.G. Using a virtual environment when you want to use a global one.

You must point PyCharm to the correct interpreter that you want to use.

"File/Settings(Preferences On Mac)/Project: ... /Project Interpreter" takes you to the settings associated with the interpreters.

This window shows all of the modules within the interpreter.

From here you can click the settings wheel in the top right and configure your interpreters. (add virtual environments and what not)

or you can select an existing interpreter from the drop down to use with your project.